# Counting wide rows in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

We are running Apache Cassandra 2.1.X and using Datastax driver. I've a use case where we need keep a count of various things. I came up with schema something like this:

```
create table count{
partitionKey bigInt,
type text,
uniqueId uuid,
primary_key(partitionKey, type, uniqueId)
```

So this is nothing but wide rows. My question is if I do something like
`select count(uniqueId) from count where paritionKey=987 and type='someType'` and this returns back with say 150k count.

- Will it be a expensive operation for Cassandra? Is there a better way to compute count like this. I also want to know  if anyone has solved something like this before?
- I would prefer to stay away from keeping counter as it's not that accurate and keeping count at application level is anyways doomed to fail.
- Also it will great to know how does Cassandra internally compute such data.

A big thanks to folks who help the community!

Answer (score 0):

**Even if you specify partition key cassandra still needs to read 150k cell to give you the count**

If you haven't specify the partition key cassandra needs to scan all the node's all row to give you the count.

Best Approach is to use counter table.

```
CREATE TABLE id_count (
    partitionkey bigint,
    type text,
    count counter,
    PRIMARY KEY ((partitionkey, type))
);
```

Whenever a uniqueId insert increment the count here.

Comment: Thank you @Ashrauful. From my research counter in Cassandra is not accurate and count can go off sync. In my use case i would need an accurate count. Do you think this approach will work? Do you have any oyher recommendations?

Comment: @Coder You can write a background task, which will sync your count.